# Is it possible to have an MVC 1 csproj file that will be compatible with both VS2010 and VS2008?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, project

I have an accomplice who is using VS2008 and I am also, but I want to switch to VS2010. He is not going to switch, but as soon as I switch I have to convert the project (which doesn't really go that smoothly and takes some time to fix up) and if I commit it back to the repo then it won't work at all for him. Is there any way for us both to use our version of choice? I don't want to have to convert it every single day...

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy way to work this. You two need to stay on the same version unless you want these sort of headaches.

You can create two CSProj files, commit both and open the one you want to work with; but that still doesn't handle keeping it up to date when you update the project with a new class.